# Как с помощью python получать результат команды в терминале и при этом получать результат по мере выполнения этой команды?

Tags: python, bash, cmd, консоль, windows-10

Я знаю, что получить результат команды из терминала, можно получить таким кодом на python:

```py
import subprocess

command = ['ipconfig']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.IGNORE)
text = p.stdout.read()
retcode = p.wait()
```

Здесь, я получаю результат выполнения команды, когда она **закончится**, ну а если запустить бесконечный ping, например, то результат я не получу. Так как мне получать результат команды по мере её выполнения на python?

Моя ОС: Windows 10

Но если такое возможно, приведите кросс-платформенное решение.

UPD:
Я Имел ввиду, что как только терминал даст какой-нибудь результат, сразу же записывать его в переменную, примерно так:

```py
import threading
import module_name #Какой-то модуль
from time import sleep

cmd = input()
result = ""
def term_res():
    while True:
        result += module_name.get_res_from_cmd(cmd)


thread = threading.Thread(target=term_res, daemon=True)
thread.start()

while True:
    print(result)
    sleep(10)
```

Comment: Как вы хотите получить "бесконечный" результат в конечную переменную? Уточните ограничения.

Comment: Я Имел ввиду, что как только терминал даст какой-нибудь результат, сразу же записывать его в переменную, примерно так:
```python
import threading
import module_name #Какой-то модуль
from time import sleep

cmd = input()
result = ""
def term_res():
 result += module_name.get_res_from_cmd(cmd)


potok = threading.Thread(target=term_res, daemon=True)
potok.start()

while True:
 print(result)
 sleep(10)
```

Comment: Раз уж вы указали `[cmd]`, то, посмотрите вариант для Windows: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141679/384202 На счёт кросс-платформенное - не проверял

Comment: @dimimir укажите все дополнения в самом вопросе с помощью [кнопки править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1145505/edit).

Comment: @вася изменил вопрос!

Comment: а зачем вы хотите получать то, что пишет консоль?

Comment: @Insider я хочу сделать эмулятор командной строки

Comment: Advice: Не называйте переменные по-русски.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня не получилось найти ответ в интернете, но комментариях предложили: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141679/384202 . Этот ответ работает для Windows, но как я понял для других ОС расширение .bat надо просто поменять на другое, которое выполняет их терминал.